Получить полное описание из клипа VKontakte Api
Всем привет, при попытке получить описание из клипа вк группы с помощью токена группы и longpool получаю в ответе параметр description, который отвечает за описание клипа ВК, он возвращается укороченным, тобишь срезанным символом точки (до 213 символов). С чем это может быть связано?
Мой запрос выглядит следующим образом
    try:
        response = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getLongPollServer", params={
            'access_token': VK_TOKEN,
            'v': API_VERSION,
            'group_id': VK_GROUP_ID
        }).json()
        response_local = response

        server = response['response'].get("server")
        key = response['response'].get("key")
        ts = response['response'].get("ts")
    ###
    updates = requests.get(server, params={'act': 'a_check', 'key': key, 'ts': ts, 'wait': 25}).json()
    ts = updates['ts']

    for update in updates['updates']:
        if update['type'] == 'wall_post_new':
            post = update['object']
            if latest_post_id is None or post['id'] != latest_post_id:
                latest_post_id = post['id']
                await send_post_to_telegram(post)
    ###
    async def send_post_to_telegram(post):

       attachments = post.get('attachments', [])
       for attachment in attachments:
          if attachment['type'] == 'video':
            video = attachment['video']
            video_id = f"{video['owner_id']}_{video['id']}"

            video_description = video.get('description', "")```

